# display image via imageurl in listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, html

Not sure how to explain this but I have a mysql syntax odbc connection bound to a sqldatasource like so:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ODBCDataConnectionString %>" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ODBCDataConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT User.FirstName, User.SecondName, User.Aboutme, User.DOB, Pictures.picturepath FROM User LEFT JOIN Pictures ON User.UserID = Pictures.UserID">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I save the Image**URL** to the database and im trying to change part of my listview so I can display that image, every attempt ive tryed either results in server tag not well formed if I use an asp image or only the url path being displayed if i use a html img control. How can I combat one of these so I can display images via a imageurl in my listview?

```
    <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
        EnableModelValidation="True" GroupItemCount="3">
        <AlternatingItemTemplate>
            <td runat="server" style="background-color:#FFF8DC;">
                FirstName:
                <asp:Label ID="FirstNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>' />
                <br />SecondName:
                <asp:Label ID="SecondNameLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("SecondName") %>' />
                <br />Aboutme:
                <asp:Label ID="AboutmeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Aboutme") %>' />
                <br />
                DOB:
                <asp:Label ID="DOBLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DOB") %>' />
                <br />
                picturepath:
                <img alt="" src="<%# Eval("picturepath") %>" />
                <%--<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="<%# Eval("picturepath") %>" />--%>

<%--                <asp:Label ID="picturepathLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("picturepath") %>' />--%>
                <br />
            </td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use a server control in template part of other server controls.

but the only solution is inserting img tag in your template. but a problem still remains. your image url maybe have **~** indicating application Path.

You can use code bellow to correct this problem too.

```
<img alt="" src="<%# Eval("picturepath").Tostring()
     .Replace("~/", "http://" + Request.Url.Host + "/" + 
     (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.ApplicationPath)?
         string.Empty:Request.ApplicationPath + "/") %>" />
```

This will correct your problem

Answer (score 0):

Change double quotes " " to single quote ' ':

```
src="<%# Eval("picturepath") %>" />
```

to

```
src='<%# Eval("picturepath") %>' />
```