# Sanitizing Image Path for ListView Display

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I am storing my image paths in a DB and am rendering them in a ListView.

```
<img src='<%# Eval("MainImagePath") %>' alt='<%# Eval("Title") %>' />
```

It's not rendering because of backslashes. From the generated markup:

```
~\eventimages\23297700618245dcb46c7501574e3e94_placeholder2200x133.jpg
```

How can I use a string Replace method to generate this with forward slashes? I tried the answer here but couldn't get it to work:

[display image via imageurl in listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523175/display-image-via-imageurl-in-listview)

**UPDATE**

I tried:

```
<img src='<%# Eval("MainImagePath").ToString().Replace("\", "/") %>' 
    alt='<%# Eval("Title") %>' />
```

...but got error "CS1010: Newline in constant"

Comment: Couldn't work - meaning back slash didn't get replaced? or? Can you post the image URL for the generated html?

Comment: Ray, will update the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try double slash it.

```
<img src='<%# Eval("MainImagePath").ToString().Replace("\\", "/") %>' 
    alt='<%# Eval("Title") %>' />
```

Comment: Figured it out... it should be a relative path so I have to lose the tilda in the DB update.

Comment: Glad it helped. Once the compiling error is resolved. It's easier to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply update your addresses in the database and replace backslashes with slash. This is the first solution which passes my mind. As well you can write a module to replace backslashes for you while sending the response back to the user. I think it is better to use slashes always for compatibility and portability reasons.

Comment: I'm looking for the syntax to change it in the first line in the question.